# how to use PasswordChangeView django 2.2

Tags: python, django

I've to try make a change password page with `Django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordChangeView` like:

*[views.py]*

```
class ChangePasswordView(LoginRequiredMixin, PasswordChangeView):
    template_name = 'accounts/password_change.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('account:password_change_done')


class ChangePasswordDoneView(LoginRequiredMixin, PasswordChangeDoneView):
    template_name = 'accounts/password_change_done.html'
```

With URL like:

*[urls.py]*

```
path('profile/update/password/', views.ChangePasswordView.as_view(),
         name='password_change'),
    path('profile/update/password/success/', views.ChangePasswordDoneView.as_view(),
         name='password_change_done'),
```

I use custom user, but I look the source code, Django get the user by request.user so its not be a problem if I use the custom user.
But why my change password not work, if I change the password with right old password and new password the form return the success page but not changing my password and I try to use wrong password in old password but always return the success page. What's the problem?

Comment: Can you share your custom user model? Have you set the setting `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to your custom user model?

Comment: This solved my problem - but I am using Django 4.0 - does this still hold true for version 4.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

iam so sory, my problem is in my form action not to password_change url but in my success url. my fail not check this. thanks